# Image don't show in built window

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, wpf-controls

I am building an app where I want to add object with different content to a `ScrollViewer`.

I'm doing this by creating a frame and then put my pages into it.

Unfortunately, when I start the program and load the page in, no image appears. The textblocks appears.

```
private void createNewRaid_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)  
{
    Page RaidContent = new Raid();
    Frame RaidFrame = new Frame();
    RaidFrame.Content = RaidContent;
    RaidPanel.Children.Add(RaidFrame);
}
```

This is my image on the page

```
<Image Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Height="80" Source="/Assets/Maps/Img100.png" />
```

I also tried this approach but then neither on the page the image is display
App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="myImage" UriSource="Img100.png" />
</Application.Resources>
```

Page:

```
<Image Source="{StaticResource myImage}" />
```

Page: https://imagesharing.com//photo.php?s=51sgpzvn

Window: https://imagesharing.com//photo.php?s=c950xk3t

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Are there no errors? Are you trying to implement scrollviewer's background image? Please add more code.

Comment: Make sure the image file is located in a folder/subfolder named `Assets/Maps` in your Visual Studio Project, and that its `Build Action` is set to `Resource`.